# OR operator in Smarty

Tags: smarty

I don't know if this can be classified as a bug, so I am sorry if this is posted in the wrong section.

**I am trying to make the following work:**

```
{if (preg_match("/Nokia308/i",$info) || preg_match("/Nokia309/i",$info))} 

...CONTENT... 

{/if}
```

**With no joy result, however:**

```
{if preg_match("/Nokia308/i",$info)}
{if preg_match("/Nokia309/i",$info)}

...CONTENT... 

{/if} 
{/if}
```

Works even though it is very messy coding.

Basically I want to display some content if `preg_match("/Nokia308/i",$info)` or `preg_match("/Nokia309/i",$info)` is set.

I can't see what I am doing wrong, could anybody shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve but using:

```
(preg_match("/Nokia308/i",$info) || preg_match("/Nokia309/i",$info)
```

condition, you want to make this condition true if the `$info` variable contains `Nokia308` or `Nokia309` case-insensitive.

So if you assign:

```
$smarty->assign('info','Nokia307');
```

no `...CONTENT...` string will be displayed but if you assign:

```
$smarty->assign('info','Nokia308');
```

or

```
$smarty->assign('info','Nokia309');
```

or

```
$smarty->assign('info','NOKIA308');
```

`...CONTENT...` string will be displayed.

So everything is working here as it should.

Comment: I agree with you. But here `$info` does not have any static value. I use PHP predefined `GLOBAL VARIABLE` for getting $info `$info = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`

Comment: @RohitJindal So there is no problem here. If `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` contains `Nokia308` or `Nokia309` the message will be displayed. I don't see anything that couldn't work here or you cannot explain what's the problem